# Background image for div not touching the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I'll try to explain this the best that I can. I'm working on a website right now and I want a background image of one of my divs to fall behind the footer.

I've got it working when the image has a height of 450px but when I try to change it to 350px there is white space between it and the footer. As if there is 100px of space between it and the bottom of the page now.

In Chrome it looks fine no matter the size, but all other browsers it creates white space.

Here is my current HTML and CSS for the footer div and the div that is not working properly.

```
<div class="testimonials">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'testimonial-widget' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="navbar-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <p class="footer-content">Some content...</p>

        <p class="footer-content-mobile">Some content...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <img src="/wp-content/themes/tct/inc/assets/footer.png" />
</footer>


.testimonials {
     background-image: url('/wp-content/themes/tct/inc/assets/mug.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 100% 70%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 350px;
     margin-bottom: -300px;
     font-size: 24px;

}

footer {
     word-wrap: normal;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

footer a {
     color: #ffffff;
}

footer a:visited {
     color: inherit;
}

footer a:hover {
     color: #404040;
}

@media (min-width: 981px) {
     footer img {
         height: 300px;
         width: 100%;
         top: -9999px;  
         z-index: 10;
     }

     .footer-content-mobile {
         display: none;
     }
}

.footer-content {
     color: #ffffff;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 250px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-size: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.bullet {
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
```

And lastly, here are screenshot of how it's supposed to look (it looks fine in Chrome) and how it's not supposed to look (how it looks in all other browsers).

Correct:
[image: Correct Footer]

Incorrect:
[image: Incorrect Footer]

Hopefully I explained everything enough so you understand my problem. Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Links to the images that I am using:
Mug: http://i60.tinypic.com/f4g3t3.jpg
Footer: http://i59.tinypic.com/xfq6x5.png

Comment: Can you recreate this is a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Moob Let me give it a shot.

Comment: I want to tinker with the jsfiddle when it get's up. But try `background-size: cover` on your `html` tag.

Comment: Here is the Fiddle, although it doesn't seem to be working there either. Not sure if I'm missing something or what. Sorry if it's not much help :/
http://jsfiddle.net/e2g12qdq/

Comment: It feels like you're doing this the most complicated way you can! Why not just position *both* the `testimonial` and the `footer` absolutely - one on top of the other? That way there's no negative margins to mess about with.

Comment: @Moob Would that still allow the mug picture to fall behind the footer? My footer is a PNG so that content can fall inside the "cutout part".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap all this into another container and set explicit height to it and `position: relative`

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 370px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.testimonials {
     background-image: url('http://oi60.tinypic.com/f4g3t3.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: 100% 70%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 350px;
     margin-bottom: -300px;
     font-size: 24px;

}

footer {
     word-wrap: normal;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
}

footer a {
     color: #ffffff;
}

footer a:visited {
     color: inherit;
}

footer a:hover {
     color: #404040;
}

@media (min-width: 981px) {
     footer img {
         height: 300px;
         width: 100%;
         top: -9999px;  
         z-index: 10;
     }

     .footer-content-mobile {
         display: none;
     }
}

.footer-content {
     color: #ffffff;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     top: 250px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-size: 20px;
     padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.bullet {
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="testimonials">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'testimonial-widget' ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="navbar-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <p class="footer-content">Some content...</p>

        <p class="footer-content-mobile">Some content...</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <img src="http://oi59.tinypic.com/xfq6x5.jpg" />
</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

increase value of height

```
.testimonials {
background-image: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/f4g3t3.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: 100% 70%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 560px;      //in my case
margin-bottom: -300px;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

or try it

```
footer {
word-wrap: normal;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 110px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to include that in my post. I already have that in my footer class. I just updated the post. I also included the images that I am using.

Comment: That does work, however, I only want the height to be 350px which then causes the issue I have posted about. I did manage to find something that worked for me though and I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Go through my answer again please

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that works for me for now. I'm sure it's not the way to go but it did help.

I added a negative margin-bottom of 100px to my content wrapper and that seemed to do the trick. However, that then screws up Chrome and Safari because they were rendering it properly before. So I used a conditional comment to set the bottom-margin to 0 in Chrome and Safari.

Other answers are of course welcome though!